# Unable to present a Native controller from react-native after a service(API) call

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a situation where I need call a service(API) on the button click and in the response depending on few values I have to present an iOS Native ViewController(Obj-c) from a react-native view.

I have done all the development part in both native(iOS,Android) and react-native including the bridging. For android it is working fine. But for iOS it is not working as expected.

In the Api response I am trying to present the iOS view controller but it is not presenting. I can see the logs where the methods of iOS view controller is getting called and the data which i am passing from the react-native is also binding to the models/logs.

When I tried to present the iOS native view on a simple button click it always works fine. But in in the api response it is not working.

My code looks like Below

react-native:

```
API.getMoviesFromApi("getdata", {
            "user": this.props.navigation.state.params.userId,
           }).then((responseData) => {
            this.setModalVisible(false)

              if (responseData != undefined  && responseData.status == 'Success') {
                        if(responseData.package == 'Pick'){
                            var postParam = {
                                responseData:responseData
                            };
                      if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
                        NativeModules.NativeIOSBridgeModel.navigateToTrackScreen(postParam);

                     }else{
                         NativeModules.NativeAndroidBridgeModel.navigateToTrackScreen(postParam);    
                    }

               }else{
                    var postParam = {
                        responseData:responseData
                    };
                    if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
                        NativeModules.NativeIOSBridgeModel.navigateToTrackScreen(postParam);
                    }else{
                     NativeModules.NativeAndroidBridgeModel.navigateToTrackScreen(postParam);  
                   }

                    }

            }else {
                this.refs.toast.show(responseData);
              }
           });
```

iOS Native:

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(liveTracking:(NSDictionary *)postData) {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        ViewController *mapCont= [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        mapCont.dataDict = postData;
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mapCont animated:YES completion:nil];

  });
}
```

When i put this

> NativeModules.NativeIOSBridgeModel.navigateToTrackScreen(postParam);

outside of the

> API

It works fine. Any helpful suggestions will be greatly appreciated.